# RestKit .20 mapping inner JSON array to parent id in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit-0.20

This is the JSON return, I'm trying to map the "result"->"id" and add it to the Slides Entity in Core Data, everything so far is mapping I just don't know how to access that parent id and map it into the Slides Entity

```
{
"result": {
    "id": 47,
    "type": "Slidedeck",
    "name": "Brendan Demo",
    "version": "0.24",
    "slides": [
        {
            "id": 767,
            "label": "",
            "order": 1,
            "notes": "",
            "file": "slide-38.jpg",
            "url": "http://api.testapp.com/v4/resources/767/download/slide",
            "thumb": "http://api.testapp.com/v4/resources/767/download/slide?thumb=true",
            "components": {
                "hotspots": []
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 768,
            "label": "",
            "order": 2,
            "notes": "",
            "file": "slide-54.png",
            "url": "http://api.testapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide",
            "thumb": "http://api.testapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide?thumb=true",
            "components": {
                "hotspots": []
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK"
}
```

}

My Entity Mapping and RKResponsedescriptor is as follows:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Slides"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore  defaultStore]];


[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"slideID",
                                              @"label": @"slideLabel",
                                              @"order": @"slideOrder",
                                              @"notes": @"slideNotes",
                                              @"file": @"slideFile",
                                              @"url": @"slideURL",
                                              @"thumb": @"slideThumb"
                                              }];

slidesResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:resourcesEntityMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", VERSION, @"/resources/:slideDeckID"]  keyPath:@"result.slides" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Any ideas? I've omitted all my previous attempts to accomplish this to keep the code clear. So currently there is no failed attempt code here to grab that parent result id.

**EDIT:**
I've added the @parent to the RKEntityMapping as mentioned

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"@parent.id":@"slideDeckID",
                                              @"id": @"slideID",
                                              @"label": @"slideLabel",
                                              @"order": @"slideOrder",
                                              @"notes": @"slideNotes",
                                              @"file": @"slideFile",
                                              @"url": @"slideURL",
                                              @"thumb": @"slideThumb"
                                              }];
```

also tried:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"@parent.slide.id":@"slideDeckID",
                                              @"id": @"slideID",
                                              @"label": @"slideLabel",
                                              @"order": @"slideOrder",
                                              @"notes": @"slideNotes",
                                              @"file": @"slideFile",
                                              @"url": @"slideURL",
                                              @"thumb": @"slideThumb"
                                              }];
```

but I always get the following trace messages:

Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath '@parent.id'

or

Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath '@parent.result.id'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Checked my logs, when I set the keypath to the following:

```
reourcesResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:resourcesEntityMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", VERSION, @"/resources/:slideDeckID"]  keyPath:@"result.slides" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

RestKit logs the following:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
components =     {
    hotspots =         (
    );
};
file = "slide-54.png";
id = 768;
label = "";
notes = "";
order = 2;
thumb = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide?thumb=true";
url = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide";
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x8e30af0 objectClass=Resources propertyMappings=(
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31b50 thumb => slideThumb>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31a80 @parent.id => slideDeckID>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31aa0 id => slideID>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31ad0 label => slideLabel>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31bb0 order => slideOrder>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31a50 notes => slideNotes>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31c00 file => slideFile>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e31cd0 url => slideURL>"
)>
```

Even though my response json contains the parent id element, it doesn't seem to be there to parse:

```
{
result =     {
    id = 47;
    name = "Russell Demo";
    slides =         (
                    {
            components =                 {
                hotspots =                     (
                );
            };
            file = "slide-38.jpg";
            id = 767;
            label = "";
            notes = "";
            order = 1;
            thumb = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/767/download/slide?thumb=true";
            url = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/767/download/slide";
        },
                    {
            components =                 {
                hotspots =                     (
                );
            };
            file = "slide-54.png";
            id = 768;
            label = "";
            notes = "";
            order = 2;
            thumb = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide?thumb=true";
            url = "http://api.idetailapp.com/v4/resources/768/download/slide";
        }
    );
    type = Slidedeck;
    version = "0.24";
};
status =     {
    code = 200;
    message = OK;
};
}
```

I've checked my RestKit version and get the same results when working with Development and Master branch. Verified that @parent is provided in this release in the RKMappingOperation class. Anything I'm missing here?

**Edit:**

Added the following relationship to my slides Entity mapping, but I'm still not able to get the container "result" data

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Slides"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore  defaultStore]];



[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"result"
                                                                        toKeyPath:@"slides"
                                                                      withMapping:mapping]];




[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"@parent.id":@"slideDeckID",
                                              @"id": @"slideID",
                                              @"label": @"slideLabel",
                                              @"order": @"slideOrder",
                                              @"notes": @"slideNotes",
                                              @"file": @"slideFile",
                                              @"url": @"slideURL",
                                              @"thumb": @"slideThumb"
                                              }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of RestKit defines the `@parent` metadata key which is available during mapping. So you can add a mapping like `@parent.id : @"..."` to extract the result id while mapping the slide content.

Comment: do I need to map this Slide entity as a child relationship somewhere in order to access that "parent" metadata key?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: Added edits above, but still not able to map that parent id, any ideas how my implementation is wrong?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of RestKit on the master or development branch? Have you turned on trace logging for the mapping? Try adding a breakpoint where the error message is generated so you can see what data is available during the mapping.

Comment: Using .20.3 master branch -  logging RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);, will add the breakpoints and see what's available

Comment: Added addt'l edits and some logging from RestKit, any advice?

Comment: This goes back to your original question then: "do I need to map this Slide entity as a child relationship somewhere" - it seems the answer is actually yes... It looks like specifying the key path on the response descriptor is skipping the container data so it isn't available to the mapping.

Comment: Added edits above, added RKRelationshipMapping to my Slides RKEntityMapping, still not able to get the container "result" data, am I implementing this incorrectly?

Comment: This isn't ideal... Change the source JSON if you can. You will need to change the keypath on the response descriptor. Add a mapping for the result (which is the container). Then add the relationship mapping to that.